# Extend Meteor JS find function

Tags: meteor, find, overriding

I'm looking to extend the base Meteor JS find function to create a pseudo-relational database method on the client side. I'm essentially going to curse through each line of the returned record looking for anything ending in `_id` and then run a find on the appropriate table to get the related data. I'm aware of performance issues but it's well within tolerance for my particular use cases.

I'd rather not reassign the `.find()` function for every collection I create on the client side. How do I modify the collection constructor for Meteor so that I can use my own for every collection?

**Update**

I have successfully extended the `Meteor.Collection.prototype.find` function and its subsequent fetch method. Fetch now takes a depth variable, and looks through all keys for ones ending in `_id` (except for the actual _id of the document). These keys are then used to find and fetch documents from the appropriate collections. I've also used [pluralize](https://github.com/blakeembrey/pluralize) to create a PHP Cake-esque collection naming convention that recognizes many-to-many relational collections. It's potentially expensive with MongoDB, but leveraged carefully it's turned out pretty slick.

I'll post code as an answer here soon and maybe even as a GIT if I have time.